# Android - Print To Epson Tm-M30 failing without errors

Tags: java, android, printing, development-environment, epos

The below code build without any errors, also i did all configuration successful,

While run the application in mobile does not connect to printer it is return erros, fine.

But when i run it in the connected Tablet with the same network with Epson Tm-M30 printer it is not print and no error appear. Please i need help why it is not print?

```
enter code here

           final Context sContext = this;
            Printer printer = null;
            try {
                printer = new Printer(Printer.TM_M30, Printer.MODEL_ANK, this);
            }
            catch (Epos2Exception e) {
                //Displays error messages
                Toast.makeText(sContext, "Error1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            //new
            final Context mContext = this;
            printer.setReceiveEventListener(new ReceiveListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPtrReceive(Printer printer, int code, PrinterStatusInfo printerStatusInfo, 
    String s) {
                    if (code == com.epson.epos2.Epos2CallbackCode.CODE_SUCCESS){

                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Printer can't be connected. Please try again", 
 Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });

            try {
                printer.addTextAlign(Printer.ALIGN_CENTER);
                printer.addText("Hello World");
            }
            catch (Epos2Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Can't print Hello World. Please try again", 
    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            try {
                printer.connect("TCP:192.168.100.21", Printer.PARAM_DEFAULT);
            }
            catch (Epos2Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Error1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            try {
                printer.sendData(Printer.PARAM_DEFAULT);
            }
            catch (Epos2Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Error2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
// Abort process
            }
            //public void onPtrReceive(final Printer printerObj, final int code, final PrinterStatusInfo 
    status,
            //final String printJobId) {
            ReceiveListener printrecieve_listener = new ReceiveListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPtrReceive(final Printer printerObj, final int code, PrinterStatusInfo 
    printerStatusInfo, String printJobId) {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public synchronized void run() {
                            if (code == com.epson.epos2.Epos2CallbackCode.CODE_SUCCESS) {

                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Error3", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            }
                        }
                    });
                    new Thread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public synchronized void run() {

                        }
                    }).start();
```

Comment: Any help for my issue?